# Click on "show more" button on nytimes.com with selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scroll through [this](http://www.nytimes.com/column/corner-office) page. 
After scrolling down to the bottom of the page I need to click on the "SHOW MORE" button, but I can't find it with selenium.

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('button load-more-button').click()
```

But i get an `InvalidSelectorException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code:

```
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button.load-more-button[aria-controls$='set-latest']");


//this line will scroll down to make element visible
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");

elem.click();
```

Comment: what about when you have to keep clicking 'show more' to keep loading more and more content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *find_element_by_css_selector*

```
.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button.load-more-button").click()
```

You cannot use `find_element_by_class_name` when you have multiple css classes.

The code works as shown:

```
In [22]: from selenium import webdriver


In [23]: dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

In [24]: dr.get("http://www.nytimes.com/column/corner-office")

In [25]: btn = dr.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button.load-more-button") 

In [26]: btn
Out[26]: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement at 0x7f50c34d7668>

In [27]: btn.click()
```

With Firefox, setting *.maximize_window()* also works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver


dr = webdriver.Firefox()
dr.maximize_window()
dr.get("http://www.nytimes.com/column/corner-office")

btn = dr.find_element_by_css_selector("button.load-more-button")
btn.click()
```

On Firefox and Chtorm after you click load more once you then have to scroll to get the rest, the button is not there after the initial click:

```
dr = webdriver.Firefox()
dr.maximize_window()
dr.get("http://www.nytimes.com/column/corner-office")

btn = dr.find_element_by_css_selector("button.load-more-button")
btn.click()
print( len(dr.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='headline']")))
dr.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
print( len(dr.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='headline']")))
```

Which gives you:

```
44
66
```

Comment: Thanks, i put this in a for loop for a semi-infinite scroll but after the first iteration I get `Element is not clickable at point (x,y ). Other element would receive the click:  <div class="container"></div>'`. I've also added a time.sleep(3) for the element to appear but still it doesn't become clickable

Comment: @Fotis, which webdriver are you using?

Answer (score -1):

ActionChains class can be used in case where you get exception like 'other element would receive click'.

Try below code, It should work.

```
elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button.load-more-button")

self.driver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click(elem).perform()
```